# How can I get a head-phone plug out of the jack?

Tags: technology, headphones

I just broke my headphone plug/jack. So it is now stuck inside my computer. How can I get it out?

Comment: A photo would help hugely here. Your method would depend on how much is sticking out.

Answer (score 6):

If you can add a close-up photo of it, that would be excellent.  Until then, I'll assume there is at least a millimeter sticking out. If so, try grabbing that with needle-nose pliers.

If that fails, you could CAREFULLY put a dot of Super Glue on the tip of a straightened paperclip. Press that against the headphone plug ONLY. Hold it very, very still for 10-20 seconds.  If it dried correctly (fingers crossed!) you may be able to slowly draw out the end of the plug by pulling on the paperclip. (DON'T get it stuck to anything except the plug you're trying to remove!)

[image]

Comment: The best thing to try and glue onto the remains ... is the other half of the broken plug. Just make sure you dont put on too much glue, squeeze it out and glue everything put :)

Answer (score 4):

There's a very good chance that the socket is not completely enclosed (it will most likely be in the form of a springy piece of metal with a kink in it to lock the plug in place), so if you removed your case from your computer you'd be able to push it back the other way. It should go without saying that you should disconnect all electrical power before opening the case up and avoid touching any circuit board components.

Answer (score 0):

Turn a self tapping screw into the remains of the jack a few turns and then pull on the screw with pliers.

Think of it the same way as using a corkscrew to remove a cork from a wine bottle.

Comment: A self-tapper small enough to get into a headphone jack?  Really?

Comment: It doesn't need to be small enough to fit inside the jack, it only need the first two or three half turns to "bite" and it will give you enough leverage to pull the snapped jack out.

Answer (score 0):

Really your best bet is open heart surgery on the machine.  There's a slim chance that the jack is open-backed and you can push it out from the inside.

I've done this before, it's pretty easy.  You just have to make sure you know how to take apart a computer and put it back together.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar once by taking a standard cotton/Cue tip bud and cutting the stem about half way along, then inserted it into the jack and it fitted nicely over the top of the snapped of plug, it was just a case of pulling it out :-D

Cotton bud:

http://www.compostthis.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/cotton-buds.jpg

Comment: I can't imagine how this is going to catch the broken piece of the jack